# Json in perfect form but Highcharts chart won't populate

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, highcharts

New to highcharts and as the title said I am trying to pull json from a webservice and place it into the chart (bar chart) but I am getting some weird behavior. after I pull the data down through `$http.get()` I try and set the series to that string of json like `series: '$scope.jsondata'`. It will fill some legends (more than expected) so it is getting the data. but the bars on the chart wont show.

On the other hand when I go to the [url where I am getting the json](https://api.myjson.com/bins/38qm9) and just copy and paste all of the json into the series field, it works perfectly.

I have a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Az7sHgYDEfHQoBe4Jz3x?p=preview) I have been working on that shows what I am talking about. You can just paste:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Kaia",
    "data":[19]
  },
  {
    "name":"Deborah",
    "data":[86]
  },   
  {
    "name":"Phoebe",
    "data":[77]
  },
  {
    "name":"Rory",
    "data":[17]
  },
  {
    "name":"Savannah",
    "data":[15]
  }
]
```

...into the series field and everything works.

**EDIT** I havent yet, but I am planning to use `$interval` to update the data every x seconds. Something like :

```
  $http.get(fullUrl).success(function(data2) {
    $scope.records = [];
    data2.forEach(function(r) {
      $scope.records.push(r);
    });
  });     
  mainInterval = $interval(function() {
    $http.get(fullUrl).success(function(data2) {
      $scope.records = [];
      data2.forEach(function(r) {
        $scope.records.push(r);
      });
    });
  }, 5000);
```

So like one of the answers suggested I put the chart creation in the callback of the `$http.get()` but I think that'd hinder the `$interval`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the creation of the Chart into the callback of the `get` call to simplify things. http://plnkr.co/edit/utQG34xOQmtbOukTK71e?p=preview

Note I also updated `series: '$scope.jsondata'` to `series: $scope.jsondata`.

```
$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/38qm9').success(function(ret) {
    $scope.jsondata = ret;
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Active Users'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['user']
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: 'Total Score',
            align: 'high'
          },
          labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          layout: 'horizontal',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          x: -40,
          y: 100,
          floating: false,
          backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
          shadow: false
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        series: $scope.jsondata
    });

    console.debug($scope.jsondata);
});
```

Comment: This works, but I am planning to use `$interval` to hit the url every x seconds to refresh the data. Does putting the chart inside of the callback mess that up? Seems to me like it would